# NoMethodError (undefined method `enable_standard_devise_support' for DeviseTokenAuth:Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-api

I a using DeviseTokenAuth for authentication in rails api.
By using that signup and signin modules working fine.
But but when I update it gives an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `enable_standard_devise_support' for DeviseTokenAuth:Module):
app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:35:in `set_user_by_token'
```

Without set_user_by_token resource is nil

On this line

```
if DeviseTokenAuth.enable_standard_devise_support
  devise_warden_user = warden.user(rc.to_s.underscore.to_sym)
  if devise_warden_user && devise_warden_user.tokens[@client_id].nil?
    @used_auth_by_token = false
    @resource = devise_warden_user
    @resource.create_new_auth_token
  end
end
```

Comment: what about showing us some code?

Comment: Where does this code come from, I've never seen such a thing in Devise? What it this `DeviseTokenAuth.enable_standard_devise_support` for?

Comment: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb

Comment: Can u send me ur file

Comment: so you did `git clone` of this project and it just didn't work?